# Filling an array using a method

Tags: java, arrays, oop, methods

I'm stuck with a revision question from a lab. The question is:
Write a static method to initialize an array of integers called numList. The size of the array should be passed as an int to the method and the array should be returned. Each odd index position should contain the value -1 and each even numbered position should contain the index value. Thus, such an array might contain {0,-1,2,-1,4,-1,6,-1}.

My code is currently :

```
public class initializeArray{
  public static void main (String [] args) {
       int [] numList = new int [6];
       alterArray(numList);
    }

public static void alterArray (int [] numList)
   {
    for( int i = 0; i<numList.length; i++)
     {
      if (i == 0)
     {
        numList[i] = i;
     } else{
        numList[i] = -1;
    }
   }
System.out.println( "The array is: " + numList);}
}
```

The return that I'm getting is :
"The array is: [I@1ef856c"
Thanks.

Updated to:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numList));
```

Error now occuring:
"Cannot find symbol - variable Arrays"

Comment: Try using `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numList));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numList));
```

Comment: It says that the variable Arrays cannot be found

Comment: You have to add this in your import: "import java.util.Arrays;"

Comment: Brilliant thanks that worked. Is there any way to make that class work with using imports?

Comment: Your revision question only asks you to store the values  In the array so technically you don't even need to print it out as you've already seen what's in the array.

Comment: I didn't even realize that! well at least I know for future now Thanks!

Comment: no worries, also if you dont want use the Arrays.toString, you could just use a for loop to print the values.  

System.out.println( "The array is:");
for( int i = 0; i<numList.length; i++){ 
 System.out.println(numList[i]+",");
}